# Flask authentication and blueprints

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to protect my pages using basic login_required method. This is working fine for main page (dashboard) but not for loaded blueprints. Any way of protecting them too?
I'd like to keep my app modular rather than having all my code in main app.

I have the following:

```
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'T0pS3cr3tKeY!'

def login_required(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrap(*args, **kwargs):
        if 'logged_in' in flask.session:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            flask.flash('You need to login first!')
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('/'))
    return wrap


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if flask.request.method == 'POST':
        if flask.request.form['email'] != 'admin' or flask.request.form['password'] != 'admin':
            error = 'Invalid login details, please try again.'
        else:
            flask.session['logged_in'] = True
            flask.flash('You were just logged in!')
            return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('dashboard'))
    return flask.render_template('login.html', error = error)


@app.route('/dashboard')
@login_required
def dashboard():
    return flask.render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    flask.session.pop('logged_in', None)
    flask.flash('You were just logged out!')
    return flask.redirect(flask.url_for('login'))


app.register_blueprint(app1)
app.register_blueprint(app2)
app.register_blueprint(app3)
```

Comment: Basically you need to apply `@login_required` to each view in your blueprints, just like the dashboard view.

Comment: ok but i can't find a way of doing this, i presume its within module itself?

Comment: define your decorator in another script and import it into each blueprint module so that you can use @login_required with each route. Alternatively can try importing the function from the dashboard module but if that imports your otehr apps you may be complicating the import dependency chain

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply `@login_required` to all paths, you can use [the `@app.before_request` decorator](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/api/?highlight=before_request#flask.Blueprint.before_request). I think that would work with other blueprints.

Then if you want to add an exception for `/`, you could do that as an if statement inside the decorated function.

Alternatively you can move that decorator into it's own blueprint, and then register one blueprint in another blueprint. (Doing some testing, it looks like the order of that nesting matters.)